# Model Builder: Iterating files; Don't know what to make "input" in later tool

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder

I have a simple model where I am trying to iterate through a year of daily tif's and recode everything in them as either snow covered ground or not snow.

My problem is I have no clue what to put into the "input raster" field when I get to the reclass by table tool. I'm limited on model builder and python experience and am walking myself through this using grad school tutorials I found. In some of these resources, its indicated to leave the input raster field blank as the iterate function will generate new names for each file it sends to the tool. This can't be the case since, as the photos show, the model isn't even complete without this input. I have also tried using the %Name% variable (model wouldn't verify) and also got desperate and just put something random hoping the iteration would somehow override it (stupid, I know).

What am I missing? Is there a larger issue in the way or is it as simple as just being new at this and not knowing the iterate output?

First image: dialogue for the iterate function showing some constraints on file names and types. 
Second: dialogue for the reclass by table tool showing empty "input raster" field.

[image: dialogue for the iterate function showing some constraints on file names and types]

[image: dialogue for the reclass by table tool showing empty "input raster" field.]

Comment: Don't use Iterate files use Iterate Rasters!

Comment: didn't see that option! i'll give it a try over lunch break.